# Namespace declaration statement error

Tags: laravel-5

I'm trying to use this to create a form my website, but it can display namespace declaration error.

Error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

> FatalErrorException in : 
>                   C:\wamp64\www\l52\vendor\illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider.php line
>   2:

HtmlServiceProvieder.php

```
         <?php 
        namespace Illuminate\Html;

        use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

        class HtmlServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

            /**
             * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
             *
             * @var bool
             */
            protected $defer = true;

            /**
             * Register the service provider.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            public function register()
            {
                $this->registerHtmlBuilder();

                $this->registerFormBuilder();

                $this->app->alias('html', 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlBuilder');
                $this->app->alias('form', 'Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder');
            }

            /**
             * Register the HTML builder instance.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            protected function registerHtmlBuilder()
            {
                $this->app->singleton('html', function($app)
                {
                    return new HtmlBuilder($app['url']);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Register the form builder instance.
             *
             * @return void
             */
            protected function registerFormBuilder()
            {
                $this->app->singleton('form', function($app)
                {
                    $form = new FormBuilder($app['html'], $app['url'], $app['session.store']->getToken());

                    return $form->setSessionStore($app['session.store']);
                });
            }

            /**
             * Get the services provided by the provider.
             *
             * @return array
             */
            public function provides()
            {
                return array('html', 'form');
            }

        }
   ?>
```

composer require "illuminate/html":"5.*"

```
        Open config/app.php and update as follows:

        'providers' => [
           ...
           Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
        ],

        'aliases' => [
             ...

            'Form'=> Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 
            'Html'=> Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the space in front of `<?php`?

Comment: now it display second error 
ErrorException in C:\wamp64\www\l52\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader.php line 66:
Class 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacades' not found (View: